# Bold text in PHP form (website contact to email)

Tags: php

I finally manged to get my contact form on my website to work, however, when it comes through via email, it's very plain. Would it be possible to try and get some words bolded under the email content settings? I'm new to all of this and I'm slowly learning but I've been stuck on this one for hours.

**Content Code:**

```
        // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Company: $company\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";
```

**Full Mailer.php code:**

```
<?php

// Only process POST requests.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $company = trim($_POST["company"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient's email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "(my company email here)";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "Website Query - $name $company";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Company: $company\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

Comment: Where are you viewing this e-mail? In some client or in webmail?

Comment: I'm viewing it in a Webmail type platform.

Comment: If it's a webmail, then you can look at the HTML source of the message. Are the bold tags rendered and properly placed?

Answer (score 0):

You would use standard html syntax.
So, send an email with bold text in it, you'd simply send

```
<b>Bold Text</b>
```

In your case, do this

```
$temp_message = trim($_POST["message"]);
//Find which part you want to bold or do this to make the whole thing bold.
$message = "<b>"+$temp_message+"</b>"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work :( The first thing I tried, it didn't pull through on the email

Comment: You would put $message directly in $email_content. The way your code is right now, html tags would be parsed as text.

Comment: Please note that `+` is not PHP concatenation syntax.

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately. Maybe I need to revisit the entire code and go back from start to finish??